ATF step configurations in ServiceNow (Reports and Responsive Dashboards)
I am facing an issue like while I am adding the test step for reporting testcase or for dashboard testcase I am unable to open, the page was stuck and is showing like this. What can I try next?
Screenshot of tried report test step in atf in Servicenow

